# JQXChart - how to get image binary (e.g. dataURL) of a chart

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, jqxwidgets

I'm having a JQXChart on a page:

```
$('#chartContainer').jqxChart(settings);
```

What I'd like to do is the push this chart - as an image - to the server. 
The component supports functionality like export to image:

https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxchart/index.htm#demos/jqxchart/javascript_chart_export_jpeg.htm

But I can't see any possibility to just getting the image, without actually downloading it by a web browser. I have to pass this image to the back-end service.

I saw this kind of functionality in another JS framework:

http://www.jqchart.com/jquery/chart/ChartFeatures/ImageDataURL

Is it possible in jqwidgets? Or... somehow achievable through html5...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation you linked it seems that the methods to export images support two arguments: `fileName` and `exportServer`. The documentation further states:

> If you don't setup your own export server the default server is jqwidgets.com.

This causes the behavior of creating a download link as you described and can be seen on the [example page](https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxchart/javascript_chart_export_jpeg.htm?light). But there is no reason you shouldn't be able to use your own server. Since you want to push the image to your backend server anyway, just set up a corresponding route and use it in the method like:

`$('#chartContainer').jqxChart('saveAsJPEG', 'myChart.jpeg', 'http://www.yourserver.com/export')`

See what arrives on the server side and go from there.